# Create new object from other typescript (VueJS project) Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

i have the following

```
export type SelectedFilters = {
  organization: string | null;
  status: string[];
  priority: string | null;
};
```

when declaring the variable in the component, it's like this:

```
selectedFilters: SelectedFilters = {
      organization: null,
      status: [],
      priority: null,
    };
```

then, i need to create another object from this, when user clicks on something in the page, where the change is basically in the array
like if

```
selectedFilters.status = ['filter1', 'filter2', 'filter3'];
```

i need to transform it to

```
newObject.status = 'filter1,filter2,filter3'
```

so i tried to create this function:

```
createQuery(): Dictionary<string | (string | null)[]> {
      const query: Dictionary<string | (string | null)[]> = {};

      Object.keys(this.selectedFilters).forEach((filter) => {
        if (typeof this.selectedFilters[filter] !== 'object') {
          query[filter] = this.selectedFilters[filter];
        } else {
          query[filter] = this.selectedFilters[filter].join(',');
        }
      });

      return query;
    }
```

but this gives me the following error:
***Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'SelectedFilters'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'SelectedFilters'.***

i need help fixing this problem

Comment: did you try out `status: string[]|string;`

Comment: yes @BoussadjraBrahim, but it doesn't work..as far as i know this relates to, in the forEach function, the filter variable could not be one of the properties in the SelectedFilter types, like the properties are "organization", "status", "priority", and it assumes that filter could be "test" for example

Comment: https://effectivetypescript.com/2020/05/26/iterate-objects/

Comment: Yeah this is what i was looking for @larizzatg. Thanks!